# Filter activeadmin with hstore

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I would like to use activeadmin filters with hstore:

In model I have got column amenities with Room.

I would like to do sth like this:

> filter :amenities, :as => :select, :collection => proc
>   {Room.all.map{|r| r.amenities} }

Answer (score 5):

You could just create a Formtastic custom input for the HStore Datatype. If you don't want the Hstore values to be editable this should be sufficient (you could additionally set the the input field to read-only with input_html_options):

```
class HstoreInput < Formtastic::Inputs::StringInput

end
```

This will break the attribute values on write though.

Comment: file location: `/app/inputs/hstore_input.rb`

Answer (score 3):

With latest `activeadmin` (which uses [ransack](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack) instead of [meta_search](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/meta_search)) it's possible to define a custom `ransacker` for hstore field in a model:

```
class Room < ActiveRecord::Base
  store_accessor :options, :amenities

  ransacker :amenities do |parent|
    Arel::Nodes::InfixOperation.new('->', parent.table[:options], 'amenities')
  end
end
```

Then it can be used in `activeadmin` for filtering:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Room do
  filter :amenities_eq, label: 'Amenities', as: :select # ...
end
```