# Activeadmin and Formtastic with HStore column

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin, formtastic, ransack, hstore

I am unable to edit or add a new model in activeadmin that has an HStore column due to the following error.

```
Unable to find input class for hstore
```

How can I get activeadmin and formtastic to play nice with my HStore column?  This question has been asked but I cannot find a definitive answer that allows for adding and editing of the hstore field.

***I have used these references so far***

With latest activeadmin (which uses ransack instead of meta_search) it's possible to define a custom ransacker for hstore field in a model:

```
class Room < ActiveRecord::Base
  store_accessor :options, :amenities

  ransacker :amenities do |parent|
    Arel::Nodes::InfixOperation.new('->', parent.table[:options], 'amenities')
  end
end
```

Then it can be used in activeadmin for filtering:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Room do
  filter :amenities_eq, label: 'Amenities', as: :select # ...
end
```

[Filter activeadmin with hstore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14605710/filter-activeadmin-with-hstore)

and

https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/issues/2032

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who happens to stumble across this, I was able to use the [activeadmin_hstore_editor](https://github.com/wild-r/activeadmin_hstore_editor) gem for this purpose, which gives a way to input arbitrary json into an input field.